# Fundamental Subspaces Theorem's proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

According to the theorem of fundamental subspaces if A is $m \times n$ matrix, then $N(A) = R(A^T)^\bot$ and $N(A^T)$ = $R(A)^\bot$. The proof from Linear Algebra with Applications book by Steven J.Leon is:

> On the other hand, we have already seen that $N(A) \bot R(A)^\bot$, and this implies that $N(A)\subset R(A^T)^\bot$. On the other hand, if $\mathbf{x}$ is any vector in $R(A^T)^\bot$, then $\textbf{x}$ is orthogonal to each of the column vectors of $A^T$ and consequently, $A\textbf{x} = 0$. Thus, **x** must be an element of $N(A)$ and hence $N(A) = R(A^T)^\bot$.

Can someone explain this proof with more details? Especially the part where it says

> On the other hand, if **x** is any vector in $R(A^T)^\bot$, then **x** is orthogonal to each of the column vectors of $A^T$ and consequently, $A\textbf{x} = 0.$

Comment: $x$ is orthogonal to each row of $A$, hence $Ax=0$.

Comment: Well that is one of the things I don't understand. Why would a linear combination of the column vectors of A that results in a zero, be true for row vectors of A. Can you explain this?

Comment: There is nothing said about the columns of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I suppose that $R(A)$ denotes the range/column space of $A$.)

By definition, if $x\in R(A^T)^\perp$, then $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $R(A^T)$, including of course every column vector of $A^T$, which is just the transpose of a row vector of $A.$  Now, each component of $Ax$ is the product of a row vector of $A$ and $x$, so it must be zero.  Hence $Ax$ is a vector consisting of all zeros, i.e. $Ax=0$.